# Can not start Spring application in tomcat with maven plugin

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat, plugins

I run maven goals "clean install" with Maven Tomcat Plugin:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>

    <configuration>
        <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html</url>
        <server>TomcatServer</server>
        <failOnError>false</failOnError>
        <path>/spring-training</path>
        <fork>true</fork>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>01-start-tomcat</id>
            <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>02-stop-tomcat</id>
            <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>shutdown</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and get error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'logBeanFactoryPostProcessor' defined in URL [jar:file:/D:/projects/MainSpringProject/SpringSubProject/General/target/General-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/com/springproject/ioc/LogBeanFactoryPostProcessor.class]: BeanPostProcessor before instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0' while setting bean property 'transactionAttributeSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0': Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: warning no match for this type name: com.noveogroup.springtrainig.service.ApplicationService [Xlint:invalidAbsoluteTypeName]
```

I **pay you attention** if I run maven "clean package" and manually deploy into tomcat there are **no errors!**, but when I the same with tomcat-maven-plugin I get such errors. What is the problem may be?

Comment: You seem to have multiple modules, so I'd suspect having a different classpath (old, incomplete, etc) when deploying from maven. Can you share the full maven configuration?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with a simpler (and more up to date) configuration:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.0</version>
    <configuration>
      <port>9090</port>
      <useTestClasspath>true</useTestClasspath>
      <path>/</path>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Then you should be able to start tomcat using the command line:

```
mvn tomcat7:run
```

Note that this starts an embedded tomcat server, which ensures that you have no dependency on where you might have installed Tomcat on the build machine.